# @Id @GeneratedValue but set own ID value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with a generated id, but in some cases I would like to set it on my own. Can I, somehow, force Hibernate to ignore the @GeneratedValue?

Comment: Have you tried it, see what happens?

Comment: Yes, Hibernate does not care if the id is set or not - a value is generated anyway.

Comment: I knew I'd seen this before somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89439/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate - use `merge()` rather than `persist()`

Comment: Don't forget to say entity=merge(entity). The returned entity is the managed one; the original one remains unmanaged.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, my entity still gets a generated id, although i use merge

Comment: @woezelmann Show your mapping and how do you save a new Entity, please. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be an overkill but have you thought about writing your own CustomIDGenerator which probably subclasses say the AutoGenerator of hibernate and exposes a couple of methods where you can set the id of the next class object to be generated so for example

```
class MyGenerator extends .... {

public void setIdForObject(Class clazz, Long id) {
    //once you use this API, the next time an object of 
    //type clazz is saved the id is used
}

public void setIdForObject(Class clazz, Long id, Matcher matcher) {
    //once you use this API, the next time an object of 
    //type clazz is saved and the matcher matches yes the id will be 
    //assigned. Your matcher can match properties like name, age etc
    //to say the matched object
}
}
```

This could get complicated but at the least is possible as per [hibernate doco](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-enhanced)

Comment: On the hibernate.org forums, there is a user that wrote his Generator class for this exact scenario: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2404032

Comment: I stumpled upon this request looking for a solution to the exact same question (though I am using EclipseLink instead of hibernate). 

I started using a custom ID generator but (at least in my EclipseLink scenario) there is one problem: How do I know if the object that needs to be persisted already has an ID or not?

I don't have the entity object in my custom ID generator at hand. So I can't determine if I need to generate a new ID - in case the object does not have one. Or if I just return the id the object already has (or maybe null or whatever is necessary).

Comment: Add-on to my comment before: 

In EclipseLink, when creating an own Sequence generator there is a method called `shouldAlwaysOverrideExistingValue` which can be overridden. This seems to be a possible solution. 
Although it feels a little uncomfortable to override things I do not completely oversee and also didn't find any documentation to other than this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300556)  entry.

Answer (score 8):

create your own identifiergenerator/sequencegenerator

```
public class FilterIdentifierGenerator extends IdentityGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator{

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object)
            .getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
    return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object);
}

}
```

modify your entity as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="myGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name="myGenerator", strategy="package.FilterIdentifierGenerator")
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;
...
```

and while saving instead of using `persist()` use `merge()` or `update()`

Answer (score 7):

Although this question was asked quite a while ago, I found the perfect answer for it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535006/642795) by @lOranger, and wanted to share it.

This proposal checks if the object's current id is set to something other than `null`, and if so, it uses it, otherwise, it generates it using the default (or configured) generation strategy.

It's simple, straight forward, and addresses the issue brought up by @Jens, of one not being able to retrieve the object's current id.

I just implemented it (by extending the UUIDGenerator), and it works like a charm :-D

Answer (score 2):

For you use case, you can manually add this no user.
One way to do it is to put the insert operation on a file named "./import.sql" (in your classpath).
Hibernate will go execute these statements when the SessionFactory is started.

Comment: @Emmanuel Bernard He said: **but, in some cases,** i would like to set it on my own. If you define how Hibernate should save an Entity (through "/.import.sql" file), so its automatic generation of identifier will not work, do not ?

Comment: No it's unrelated, import.sql is plain SQL so you can do what you want, including updating the sequence or table id if needed