# Java/Hibernate: How can I insert a specific value for a column with autoincrement / @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, auto-increment, persist

I have a table with an id column that autoincrements, and a Java object that has a getter annotated with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`.  This works great when saving, however for a unit test I want to specify the ID so that it is deterministic.  In MySQL (the DB we are using) I can specify a value in the insert statement and everything works fine.  However if I set the id field in the java object and try to persist, hibernate throws an exception.  How can I allow Hibernate to let me specify a value for a typically generated value?

Field Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Works in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, str)
VALUES (10,'this works!')
```

Does not work:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setId(10L); //remove this line and hibernate saves ok
myObject.setStr("this does not work.");
daoForMyObject.persist(myObject); //throws org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
```

Thanks in advance for helping me be a good test-driven developer!

Comment: This has been asked before and there is a suggested solution [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2404032). Hope this helps. This post was linked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108178/id-generatedvalue-but-set-own-id-value) stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to answer in a way you probably don't want, but I think your idea is bad. If your goal is to be a good test-driven developer, don't do this. Your are basically sabotaging what you want to test. You request a special behaivour from your unit when under test. But a unit test should test the unit as it is.

If hibernate would let you set a fixed value for a autoincrement (or so) field, this could be considered a bug in hibernate. As I see it, it is good that hibernate does not allow it.

Why don't you read the id value after the `session.save()` method call? Probably your `daoForMyObject.persist()` calls `save()`, so right after that you can read the id:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setStr("this does work.");
daoForMyObject.persist(myObject);
Long id = myObject.getId();
```

Now use `id` to reference your entity instead of 10... why should you not be able to do it this way?

Comment: This is actually the way I started doing it in my tests after posting this :-P  But I am still curious how to explicitly set the value of an autoincrement field.  MySQL lets you do it, it would be nice if hibernate had same behavior as MySQL -- using auto value if not provided, otherwise use provided value.  Don't think that would be a bug.