# How to save entity with my id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

How to set id in model? I try this code:

```
public Community(Long id, ...) {
    this.id = id;
    ....
}
```

But when I do this:

```
Communtiy c = new (1, ...);
c.save();
```

Hibernate say:

```
Execution exception PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.Community
```

Comment: Please provide information about `Model`. What generation type of your id you are using?
This question seems similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108178/id-generatedvalue-but-set-own-id-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by extending from `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` instead of `play.db.jpa.Model`. This will allow you to set the primary key manually.

In fact, what `Model` does is extend from `GenericModel` and because it is very common to do so `Model` automatically generates primary keys ( by using `@Id @GeneratedValue public Long id` ). But if for whatever reason you want to set a custom primary key, then extending from `GenericModel` is the way to go.

[Official documentation here.](http://www2.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/jpa#genericmodel)

Example

```
@Entity
public class Community extends GenericModel {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public Community (Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try not set `id` on your own, `id` should be loaded to model after save.

Comment: I want to use Id from Facebook

Comment: but I assume that `id` property in your model is mapped to `id` into your DB. If you would like to store facebook `id` in DB make another field in class, `fbid` for example.