# Hibernate and generated values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-annotations

I have a column in my table that is mapped like this in my Hibernate JPA model object:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "column", nullable = false, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Long column;
```

While most of the times I want the DB to generate the value for me, there are certain times where I want to assign a value to this column manually. Is this possible?

I tried to give a value to the column from the setter method, however this is being overwritten on insert.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108178/id-generatedvalue-but-set-own-id-value possible duplicate

Comment: @pedromarce Yep duplicate and with a solution as well. Thanks for your input.