# Java Spring Hibernate : Model class primary key auto increment field : set automatic and manually on a field

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key, auto-increment, setter

in java spring hibernate maven project, i use (@Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)) together on a field to make this field P.K and Auto-increment on mysql DB.

### i want:

- this field to be auto_increment if i did not set its id manually , and if i set it manually by setter , it works fine(but currently i get error if i set manually).

### problem:

- when i left the id null , auto_increment works , but when i set it manually i get error;
  how i annotate and config the model class that i can set manually by setter and automatic pk Id (anyone i like to do)?

### my code:

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

### Annotation Detail based on java doc:

@Id :
Specifies the primary key of an entity

@GeneratedValue(strategy = ... ) :
Provides for the specification of generation strategies for the values of primary keys

- GenerationType.IDENTITY : 
  Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column.
- GenerationType.SEQUENCE : 
  Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database sequence.
- GenerationType.TABLE : 
  Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using an underlying database table to ensure uniqueness.
- GenerationType.AUTO : 
  If you use AUTO, Hibernate will choose one of the strategies to generate your id

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom id generator for this purpose as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182826/set-id-pk-generation-value-auto-and-manual) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194721/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate-merge-data-not-in-db/3218642#3218642)

Here is how its code will look like:-

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="IdOrGenerated")
@GenericGenerator(name="IdOrGenerated",strategy="....UseIdOrGenerate")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 0)
public Long getId(){..}
```

and

```
public class UseIdOrGenerate extends IdentityGenerator {    
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        if (obj == null) throw new HibernateException(new NullPointerException()) ;

        if ((((EntityWithId) obj).getId()) == null) {//id is null it means generate ID
            Serializable id = super.generate(session, obj) ;
            return id;
        } else {
            return ((EntityWithId) obj).getId();//id is not null so using assigned id.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a query: why do you have preceding 4 dots in  strategy="....UseIdOrGenerate" . What is it meant for?

Comment: Oh that's just to generically state a strategy. You would ideally have a name of a concrete strategy there.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Would have been more ideal to have the correct  syntax over there for noobs like me out there in SO who look around to learn or understand. :)