# NHibernate Manually set id for auto increment

Tags: c#, mysql, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using `NHibernate` Mapping by code with `MYSQL`, and have mapping as below :-

```
Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Column("ID"); map.Generator(Generators.Native); });
```

and database as below :-

```
ID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT
```

i used `Generators.Native` because database will generates its id by `AUTO_INCREMENT` . But i would like to manually set id `(Id=10)` in some cases. How can i change the mapping, if `Id=0` then use 'AUTO_INCREMENT' else use the already set `Id` which is 10.

I checked on internet and got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182826/set-id-pk-generation-value-auto-and-manual) (Custom Id Generator) but its for `Java` + `Hibernate`. I don't know how to convert this in`NHibernate` `mapping by code` for `C#`.

Comment: Why would you like to manually set the value of `id` "in some cases"? What are these cases? You're defeating the purpose of an Identity column and quite likely introducing problems that, if not immediate, may make themselves known months or years down the road. Your program should not be affected if there are "gaps" in ID's that are created by deleting records, which is what I'm guessing you're trying to address.

Comment: if data are getting created by frontend then we will use autoincrement, and  at run time our system is getting data from some services those have some id which need to be match with our database. For sure our database wont be having this id, so it will be safe for us to set the id and its required.

Comment: You're treading on thin ice. Suppose this generated ID already exists? Create a separate column that stores this value.

Comment: before insertion i am checking in this id exist or not, If exist then update else insert.

Answer (score 0):

In Hiberante you can define with anotation that use. For example you can define this

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Idetentity property take the auto increment from the data base.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change your Id defintion from Native to Assigned.

Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Column("ID"); map.Generator(Generators.**Assigned**); });