# How to set autogenerated Id manually?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity called Task and it has taskId field. Problem is I need to create/update some specific tasks and JPA autogenerator doesn't allow me to set taskId manually.(It overrides my taskId)

Is there any way to set taskId manually?

```
@Id
@Column(name = "task_id")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private String taskId;
```

Comment: The JPA spec doesn't allow for a user wanting to set under some situation and generate under others (since the definition of `GeneratedValue` is static). Some JPA providers do support it (DataNucleus does IIRC) but non-portable if relying on it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set Id (PK) generation value auto and manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182826/set-id-pk-generation-value-auto-and-manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Example:
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/java-hibernate-jpa-annotations-tutorial-for-beginners

Answer (score 2):

@GeneratedValue annotation doesn't allow the user to set the value manually.Instead of using that annotation you can manually generate some string format like below and mark the taskId column with @Id

```
String hql = "from MasterCount where itemType=:type";
Query<MasterCount> query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("type", "task");
MasterCount count = query.uniqueResult();
int lastId = count.getItemId() + 1;
count.setItemId(lastId);
task.setTaskId("task0"+lastId);
```

That is create a master table with columns itemId and itemType.Save "task" and 0 in the columns respectively.Check the last entered value ,increment one and save again.

Answer (score 2):

you can initialize it manually.

```
        @Id
        @Column(name= "id")
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id = Long.parseLong(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 16);
```

Comment: But here it will go to update entity insted of insert because id is not null in jpa.save() method

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182826/set-id-pk-generation-value-auto-and-manual)
may help you.

I would apply a basic solution if I understood your problem correctly.

```
@Column(name = "task_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String taskId;
```

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Just implement org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

> After too much finding and frustration i have used this and worked for my R2DBMS entity

```
@Table(name = "...")
public class .... implements Persistable<String> {

   ...

   public boolean isNew(){
     return id==null; //modify and set your logic
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

all of you missing the point.

Sometimes you need to insert a specific Id with identity_insert on especially when perform bulk imports

The tricky part is how to override the default behaviour without reinvent the wheel and do manual queries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).