# H2 in-memory database and custom @GenericGenerator strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I've tried to use custom id-generator as in [Bypass GeneratedValue in Hibernate (merge data not in db?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194721/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate-merge-data-not-in-db) and it works fine while working with Postgres DB. My code is equals to the code in example.
But while running test with H2 in-memory database I faced the problem, that id is not generated automaticaly.

**Without** custom generator

```
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Generated create table script

```
create table db.schema.entity (id  bigserial not null...
```

**With** custom generator

```
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "idGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GenericGenerator(name="idGenerator", strategy = "...UseIdOrGenerate")
private Long id;
```

Generated create table script

```
create table db.schema.entity (id int8 not null...
```

As a result tests don't work.

Comment: How do your tests look like?

Comment: @LeonidGlanz simple junit test: create and persist entity, than check that this entity exists in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing @Column

```
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigserial")
```