# Manually set auto generated id property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In Hibernate is there a way to skip generating the value of a `@GeneratedValue` property by manually setting it before calling `save` on the session?

I am building an import/export facility and I would like to preserve the IDs from a previously made export.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bypass GeneratedValue in Hibernate (merge data not in db?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194721/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate-merge-data-not-in-db)

Answer (score 2):

Is important to say, if you use this way:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

And you don't have the id you set in the database it will ignore your id set and the database will create a new one. I mean, if you have an empty database and set `user.setId(100L)` and save, when you find it in database the `service.findById(100L)` will not find any object.

Comment: So how to achieve the case you have mentioned?

Comment: Hi @Rich if you use the GenerationType.IDENTITY you just need to configure the id rules on the database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hibernate won't override value if it was already set, so everything should work as you expect. Just make sure you're not using AUTO.

If you need a more complex logic, take a look at @GenericGenerator.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-identifier

Comment: Interesting... For some reason it does still try to generate the ID. Something else is probably not working properly. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Well there you go, if you explicitly set it to "IDENTITY" then it works! Why, I don't understand...

Comment: AUTO should switch to IDENTITY on MySQL. Check that you specified MySQL dialect in your Hibernate config.

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue` will only apply it's strategy if the `id` on which you're applying this annotation is `null`/`0`.

This means that if you've manually assigned an `id` field, then `@GeneratedValue` annotation is USELESS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was using the default (`AUTO`) strategy for the `@GeneratedValue`. If I change it to explicitly specify `IDENTITY` then it works!

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

I don't really understand why though... :-)

Comment: AUTO is flimsy, especially if wrong dialect is specified.

Comment: Actually, this still doesn't work. It generates a new ID for me. (I'm using HSQLDB in this case.)

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the version of Hibernate I am using. I'm on a pretty old one: 4.3.8