# Cascading in JPA. Persist and Merge entities through the owner of association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm wondering is it possible with JPA (Hibernate) to persist and update entities indirectly through the owner of association.

There are two datasources in my project. I'm trying to find a way to share some entities between databases. For that I just have to scan it twice with each of my Entity Manager Factories. According to my idea, an `Employee` entity could be used in both databases. For that, I just need to create a `Phone` entity in the second datasource and all it fields will be migrated via Hibernate to my second database.

Here is a sample of code (I've used [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and removed imports to simplify it)

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
@lombok.Data
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE, REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "em_id")
    private Employee employee;

    private String number;

    public Phone(Employee employee, String number) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

I would like to use a Spring Data Jpa PhoneRepository configured to work with my second datasource

```
public interface PhoneRepository extends JpaRepository<Phone, Long> {}
```

And an EmployeeRepository, as I think, could be used only once to be configured with first datasource. All relations in the second database could be created automatically by Spring/Hibernate. At least, I would like this. In my tests below it configured with my second datasource for illustrative purposes only.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

Here are some tests

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Autowired
PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

/**
 * Passes successfully.
 */
@Test
public void shouldPersitPhonesCascaded() {

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(new Employee(1L, "John Snow"), "1101"));

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(new Employee(2L, "Hans Schnee"), "1103"));
}

/**
 * Causes <blockquote><pre>
 * org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID)"; SQL statement:
 * insert into employee (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-190]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
 *        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
 * ...
 * </pre></blockquote>
 */
@Test
public void shouldMergePhonesCascaded() {
    Employee employee = new Employee(1L, "John Snow");

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(employee, "1101"));

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(employee, "1102"));
}

/**
 * Works with changed Phone entity's field.
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * {@literal @}ManyToOne
 * {@literal @}JoinColumn(name = "em_id")
 *  private Employee employee;
 * </pre></blockquote>
 */
@Test
public void shouldAllowManualMerging() {
    Employee employee = new Employee(1L, "John Snow");
    employeeRepository.save(employee);

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(employee, "1101"));

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(employee, "1102"));
}
```

Ideally I would like to take an object (`Employee`) from my first datasource, put it into a wrapping entity (`Phone`) from my second datasource and update the second database without violations.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I came to the following code. First of all I needed to create a custom repository interface and implementation class that extends the `SimpleJpaRepository` and fully duplicates functionality of `SimpleJpaRepository` except for a `Save` method.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {}

public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager em;
    private final JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.em = entityManager;
        this.entityInformation = JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(domainClass, entityManager);
    }

    private static void mergeFieldsRecursively(EntityManager em, Object entity) {
        MergeColumns merge = entity.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotation(MergeColumns.class);
        if (merge != null) {
            for (String columnName : merge.value()) {
                Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(entity.getClass(), columnName);
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                Object value = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, entity);

                mergeFieldsRecursively(em, value);

                em.merge(value);
            }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        mergeFieldsRecursively(em, entity);

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

`MergeColumns` here is a simple annotation. It describes which fields should be merged before persisting an entity.

```
@Documented
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MergeColumns {

    String[] value();
}
```

`RepositoryFactoryBean` replaces `SimpleJpaRepository` with custom  implementation - `BaseRepositoryImpl`.

```
public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
        return new BaseRepositoryFactory<>(em);
    }

    private static class BaseRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private final EntityManager em;

        public BaseRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
            super(em);
            this.em = em;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new BaseRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), em);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return BaseRepositoryImpl.class;
        }
    }
}
```

...and then it should be placed in the second datasource configuration

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = SECOND_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
        transactionManagerRef = SECOND_PLATFORM_TX_MANAGER,
        basePackages = {"com.packages.to.scan"},
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class SecondDataSourceConfig { /*...*/ }
```

Some entities will be taken from my first datasource. Optionally it is possible to use some custom generator for `id` fields like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535006/4556720).

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.Data
public class Department {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
@MergeColumns({"department"})
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    private Department department;
}
```

And a `Phone` entity "wraps" them to be used with my second datasource

```
@Entity
@lombok.Data
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@MergeColumns({"employee"})
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "em_id")
    private Employee employee;

    private String number;

    public Phone(Employee employee, String number) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.number = number;
    }
}

public interface PhoneRepository extends BaseRepository<Phone, Long> {}
```

Both tests passes successfully

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
...

@Autowired
PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

@Test
public void shouldPersitPhonesCascaded() {

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(new Employee(1L, "John Snow", new Department(1L, "dev")), "1101"));
    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(new Employee(2L, "Hans Schnee", new Department(2L, "qa")), "1103"));

    assertThat(phoneRepository.findAll()).extracting(p -> p.getEmployee().getName()).containsExactly("John Snow", "Hans Schnee");
}

@Test
public void shouldMergePhonesCascaded() {
    Employee employee = new Employee(1L, "John Snow", new Department(1L, "dev"));

    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(employee, "1101"));
    phoneRepository.save(new Phone(employee, "1102"));

    assertThat(phoneRepository.findAll()).extracting(p -> p.getEmployee().getName()).containsExactly("John Snow", "John Snow");
}
```

Here is how *Hibernate* works in my first test

```
Hibernate: select department0_.id as id1_3_0_, department0_.name as name2_3_0_ from department department0_ where department0_.id=?
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_4_0_, employee0_.dept_id as dept_id3_4_0_, employee0_.name as name2_4_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into department (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into employee (dept_id, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select employee_.id, employee_.dept_id as dept_id3_4_, employee_.name as name2_4_ from employee employee_ where employee_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into phone (id, em_id, number) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select department0_.id as id1_3_0_, department0_.name as name2_3_0_ from department department0_ where department0_.id=?
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_4_0_, employee0_.dept_id as dept_id3_4_0_, employee0_.name as name2_4_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into department (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into employee (dept_id, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select employee_.id, employee_.dept_id as dept_id3_4_, employee_.name as name2_4_ from employee employee_ where employee_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into phone (id, em_id, number) values (null, ?, ?)
```

I'm not sure that this is the simplest solution, but at least it does exactly what I needed. I'm using a *Spring Boot 1.2.8*. With newer versions the realization may differ.