# Is there a way to turn off @GenericGenerator for hibernate generated entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, auto-generate

I have a hibernate generated entity

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 @Entity
 @Table(name="SOME_NAME")
 public class SomeName  implements java.io.Serializable
 { ...
```

It has an id generator that auto-generates an id for rows inserted into the table:
     @GenericGenerator(name="some.group.name.entity.SomeNameIdGenerator", strategy="some.group.name.util.UuidStringIdentifierGenerator")@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="some.group.name.entity.SomeNameIdGenerator")
     ...

Is there a way to suppress or turn off this id generator? I tried to just remove the line, but then it causes my .war file to not deploy.

Comment: Then post the code of your entity (after the modification you made), and post the error you get when deploying the war file.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194721/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate-merge-data-not-in-db